# Need help in transfering data from multiple workbooks to master workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Currently, I'm using this code to store entire rows from multiple workbooks.
It has two buttons: Clear and fill

```
Sub ClearTable()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Me.Range("5:5000").ClearContents
    Me.Range("5:500").EntireRow.AutoFit
End Sub

Sub CreateTable()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim coll As New Collection, wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, newRow As Range
    Mask = Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ThisWorkbook.Name, "*.xlsx")

    filename = Dir(Mask)
    While filename <> ""    
        If Not filename Like ThisWorkbook.Name & "*" Then coll.Add filename
        filename = Dir
    Wend

    'For Each Item In coll: Debug.Print Item: Next
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each Item In coll
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ThisWorkbook.Name, Item), , True)
        If Not wb Is Nothing Then
            Set sh = wb.Worksheets(1)
            LastRow = sh.Range("a65000").End(xlUp).Row
            If LastRow > 4 Then    
                For i = 5 To LastRow
                    Set newRow = Me.Range("a65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                    sh.Rows(i).Copy newRow
                    newRow.EntireRow.AutoFit
                Next i
            End If
            wb.Close False
        End If
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Now I have a mini project, that stores clients data (Name, City, phone № and so on).

I still have up to 50 workbooks stored in one folder.
But now I need to pull data from cells C4:C12 and it should be moved (transposed) to masterbook's A5:I5 and below.

How can it be converted to suit my current needs?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a great community to receive help in coding problems that you have shown effort to attempt. Please read [Why is "Please Help" not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and how to create a [mcve]. We will not write code for you (which is essentially what you are asking here - even if you did not intend too).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
Sub Basic_Example_1()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\test\"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 5

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next

                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("C4:C12")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)
                        'X = ActiveSheet.Range(destrange).Value
                        'XT = Application.Transpose(X)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```